# How to remove documents with broken reference in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections in Mongo:

```
db.user.find():
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "52db05e6a2cb2f36afd63c47" },
  "name": "John",
  "authority_id": { "$oid" : "52daf174a2cb2f62aed63af3" },
}
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "52db05e6a2cb2f36afd63d00" },
  "name": "Joe",
  "authority_id": { "$oid" : "52daf174a2cb2f62aed63af3" },
}
```

and

```
db.authority.find():
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "52daf174a2cb2f62aed63af3" },
  "name": "Sample Authority"
}
```

Users store reference to authority's ID through ObjectId.

Now my problem: Several authorities have been deleted and are no longer in collection. I need to find a way how to iterate through the "user" collection and delete them if their authority_id is pointing to deleted authority.

I have tried this:

```
db.user.find(
    { 
      $where: function() { 
        db.authority.find({ _id: this.authority_id }).count() == 0  
      }
     })
```

but "db" is not accessible there. Is it possible to implement reference check inside iteration?

Comment: Can I use $nin and a variable to emulate: `delete from user where authority_id not in (select id from authority)`

Answer (score 7):

You can use an aggregate to find all orphan users and then remove them.

```
const orphanUsers = db.user.aggregate([
    {
      // Join authority collection using authority_id
      $lookup: {
        from: "authority",
        localField: "authority_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "authority"
      }
    },
    // filter users without authority (means authority_id doesn't exist)
    { $match: { authority: [] } },
    // return only the _id
    { $project: { _id: "$_id" } }
])

// Delete all orphan users
db.user.deleteMany({
    _id: { $in: orphanUsers.map(({ _id }) => _id) }
})
```

Comment: This is the most effective way to do this since aggregate is introduced, thx.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove broken entries by iterating over cursor on the javascript shell or by using any Mongo driver. The following example will give you an idea to do it on javascript shell.

```
db.user.find().forEach((user) => {
    const authority = db.authority.findOne({'_id' : user.authority_id});

    if(!authority) db.user.remove({_id : user._id});
});
```

Comment: Please don't do `cursor.hasNext() == false`.  Use `!cursor.hasNext()` instead or, if you need a strict check for `false`, use `===` and maybe put `false` *first* so that it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

"$where operator expressions cannot access certain global functions or properties, such as db, that are available in the mongo shell" according to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/.

But you can try map reduce:
http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/pivot/

I would just do it in code personally, but you might have different requirements.

Comment: Can map reduce remove records ? In-code is OK but should be on the server, in java-script.

Comment: I don't think it can change any data since it's an aggregation only, but it can output results to a collection. Still takes another external process to process output afterwards. That sucks a bit :)

Comment: Well you could use a trick to output results of your map reduce job as final versions of updated documents to the same collection effectively replacing them. You can $unset extraneous fields afterwards. Sounds risky :)

Comment: yeah, ... and like a huge overhead. Thanks for ideas though.